# Does Google pixel have opencl?

Tags: android, opencl

I'm developing app in android which use OpenCl, what i want to know is google still remove OpenCl from their devices? I don't speak of Google Pixel C which use Nvidia so i can use cuda then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Google Pixel does not.

I ran [OpenCL™ Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.openclinfo) on my Google Pixel XL, and [this is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBUJH.png).

Comment: Thank you, seem google still insist on using renderscript instead of opencl.

Comment: It would also be interesting to run a `adb shell find / -iname "*CL.so*" 2>/dev/null` on the device to see if the .so are there at all or not.

Comment: Is this still true for latest Pixel 6? I see Geekbench OpenCL results for Pixel 6 in the interwebs. But maybe Geekbench is actually using Renderscript for devices with no OCL support.

Answer (score 0):

The SoC on which it is based [has an Adreno 530 GPU](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel-8346.php), which [does support OpenCL 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adreno).

So, considering [Salvatore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642872/does-google-pixel-have-opencl/40643946#40643946) it must just mean that Google simply chose not to expose the API, as that would not be a big technological limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It's OpenCL capable, but no drivers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).